# Does getElementByID returns a DOM object

Tags: javascript, dom

In javascript normally the document variable is said to represent the DOM object
But if I do `var input = document.getElementByID()` is this resulting variable 
`input` also a DOM object?

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#return_value

Comment: So it's an `Element` object and not a DOM object. But if I do typeof(input ) it just shows `object` why doesn't it show the actual type `Element`

Comment: Thats not what `typeof` does. (Check documentation of `typeof`). You should use `instanceof` (check documentation).

Comment: There is no "DOM object" DOM = Document Object Model. Yes, document is the root element of that model but it is not _the_ DOM.

Answer (score 1):

All objects that represent elements in an HTML Document inherit from [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element).

Here are some ways to verify that indeed `getElementById` returns an Element:

```js
let div = document.getElementById("div");

console.log(div.constructor.name);
console.log(div instanceof HTMLDivElement);
console.log(div instanceof HTMLElement);
console.log(div instanceof Element);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

NB: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) has limited use. It only has a few possibly outcomes (8 in ECMAScript 2020), and for all objects -- except functions -- it evaluates to "object".